# How to appropriately read in user input without manually inputting it in?

Tags: c++, input, user-input

I have been trying to figure out how to read in user input without having to manually type every example out. I am building a stone game that is supposed to familiarize me with circularly linked lists. I have to manually type out examples like this to achieve the output. Is there another approach to replace this, and read example texts?**

Here is the code I want to include the implementation in:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  int nodes, moves = 0;
  std::cin >> nodes;
  for (int index = 0; index < nodes; index++)
  {
    link_one.add(1);
  }
  
  link_one.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful workaround to obnoxiously long inputs is temporarily using a text file with the `std::getline` function. Just replace `#include <iostream>` with `#include <fstream>` until the program is done.

you can find a pretty good explanation of that [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51572325/401059).

Edit: you'll also need to change your iostream declaration to an fstream one